# How to fix this error in Mysql. "ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails."

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error when trying to enter data into one of my tables of my db. I have never gotten this error before, and don't really understand it, or why it is happening.

This is the error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`country_club`.`visit_number`, CONSTRAINT `vn_guest_id` FOREIGN KEY (`vn_guest_id`) REFERENCES `guest` (`guest_id`))

Here is my code for this table so far.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visit_number(
    visit_number int(11),
    vn_member_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    vn_guest_id int(11) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE visit_number 
ADD CONSTRAINT vn_member_id FOREIGN KEY (vn_member_id)
REFERENCES member(member_id);

ALTER TABLE visit_number 
ADD CONSTRAINT vn_guest_id FOREIGN KEY (vn_guest_id)
REFERENCES guest(guest_id);

INSERT INTO `visit_number` VALUES ('15','1','1'),
('20', '2', '2'),
('5', '3', '3'),
('18', '4', '4'),
('13', '5', '5'),
('18', '6', '6'),
('11', '7', '7'),
('4', '8', '8'),
('9', '9', '9'),
('25', '10', '10');
```

Comment: guest and member tables have same id values as you try to insert?

Comment: Most probably guest_id is wrong hence the error.